# why is macro acting different while not using namespace std and while using namespace std?

Tags: c++

in this below code ***macro 1*** is always fine

but, ***macro 2*** is not working if statement 1 is not written..why is this happening?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
//using namespace std;      //--statement 1
#define l std::cout<<       //--macro 1
#define nl std::cout<<endl; //--macro 2
int main(){
      l "testing";  
      nl  // this is not working if i dont use statement 1 
      l "a new line";
getch();
return 0;
}
```

when ***statement 1*** is not written  ***macro 2*** is producing a error stating that *'[Error]endl was not declared in this scope'*

if `cout<<` is the short version of `std::cout<<`, this error should not happen...i can not understand why is this happening...

Comment: `endl` is in `std` namespace too.

Comment: you are just missing the std:: before endl. It should be **std::endl;**

Comment: So you need `std::endl`.

Comment: `cout` is not a "short version" of `std::cout`. It *is* `std::cout`, once you've dumped it into the global namespace via `using namespace std;`.

Comment: [don't use `endl` unless you really need its side effect](http://stackoverflow.com/q/213907/995714)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the question of your MACRO.

The endl object also belongs to the std namespace, therefore either you should use

```
std::cout << std::endl;
```

or

```
using namespace std;

cout << endl;
```